# помогите, пожалуйста, с настройкой принтера LPR на Windows 10

Tags: windows, печать

всем привет, такая ситуация, есть 2 пк в одной сети на Windows 10: на одном из них стоит принтер, подключенный по usb, необходимо, чтобы другой пк в этой сети мог использовать этот принтер по протоколу LPR/LPD.

Шаги, которые были выполнены:

ПК с принтером:

1. В управлении принтерами и сканерами был выбран нужный принтер, во вкладке "Доступ" была поставлена галочка "Общий доступ к данному принтеру" и прописано имя ресурса.
2. Сетевое обнаружение включено
3. Доп. компоненты установлены: монитор портов LPR и служба LPD
4. В портах сейчас выбран порт USB (Возможно это неправильно)

ПК клиент LPR:

1. Нажимаем в принтерах и сканерах: "Добавить принтер и сканер"
2. Необ. принтер отсутствует
3. Добавить локальный или сетевой принтер
4. Создать новый порт LPR
5. Адрес LPD принтера: ip адрес первого ПК
6. Имя принтера - имя из 1 пункта для ПК с принтером

И это не работает, что могло быть упущено?